# Android JSONObject : Search function

Tags: android, search, json, android-json

I am trying to search from JSON code that has been received beforehand..

I was wondering are there any efficient way to search specific object?
Or should i use straight forward search like looping and if statement?

I have parsing the JSON successfully, and it stored in my String variable..
The JSON contains Array of Objects..

Now i want to search for specific ObjectName and get the Whole Objects..
The JSON will be like

```
   [
     {
         "name":"blank",
         "date":"2014-06-05T00:44:30Z",
         "boolean":null,
     },
     {
         "name":"hello",
         "date":"2013-05-04T00:43:20Z",
         "boolean":null,
     }
   ]
```

I want to search for name = "hello" and get the last Array returned

Can anyone show me how?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: be more specific about what you want to do..

Comment: @Prag's Thanks i have edited the question.. Could you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
String name;
JSONObject searchObject;

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourJsonString);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject currObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
    name = currObject.getString("name");

    if(name == "hello")
    {
       searchObject = currObject        
    }
}

return searchObject
```

Comment: NOT Recommended for large JSONArray. Imagine an array of 10k records where your needle happens to be the last record :-)

Answer (score 0):

For big data you can't use search in every element imagin you have a 50K user you can't search in every 50k title to found your element I advise you to the backend - Web Developer - do this it will be easier to you and more faster how you can do this? 
You just need a space to pass search text in JSON Url then post it and retrieve searched data from him

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a web server with (PHP) and set your search element in GET like this.

Then the php search function will give you the full Json needed to your search. Also you can set pagination for this search like this.

Comment: PHP is slow AF.